# Using sed to convert singular/plural words into uppercase

Tags: sed

Using one sed command I'm trying to convert all occurrences of test and tests found in a .txt file into all caps. I also want to print only the converted lines, so I'm using -n. I've been playing around for it for over an hour. The problem is that I'm able to convert one or the other (either test or tests) but not both.

Any help would be so greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: please show what you already try (for correction by explaination) and often a sample of input as expected output

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
sed -e 's/tests/TESTS/g; s/test/TEST/g; T; p;' input.txt
```

The semicolons let you execute multiple commands.

Comment: And if I want to print the lines I'd just add a p after the g ('s/tests/TESTS/gp;? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Chalmers No you have to add the p after the last semicolon.

Comment: This will print all lines.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\<tests\?\>/\U&/gp;d' file
```

This will uppercase words (`\<....\>`) that begin `test` with an optional `s` (`s\?`).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, but here is hopefully an understandable one with basic regex (no extended regex):

```sh
sed 's:\<test\(s*\)\>:TEST\1:g' < inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt; cat outputFile.txt | grep -n TEST
```

Explanation:

- `:` delimiter (instead of usual /)
- `\<test\>` matches test. The character before the first `t` can be any character except a letter, number or underscore. Same applies for the character after the last `t`.
- `\(\)` remember what is inside the parenthesis.
- `s*` match zero or more `s`'s.
- `\1` used to insert first remembered match (i.e. any number of `s`'s matched).

The rest is hopefully clear. Otherwise leave a comment.